# Where do I add easing to jquery animation?

Tags: jquery, animation

How do I add 'easeOutBounce' effect to this jquery animation?

```
$next.show().animate({marginTop: 0}, 2000, function () {
      $this.hide().css("z-index","0");
});
```

I don't know where to add the code 'easeOutBounce' without crashing it. Just before the duration doesn't work.  Here's the  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lajon/3xcu3urk/2/)

Comment: Something is weird with your fiddle. You might want to draw attention to that if those answers aren't able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an easing option between your duration and function note is the documentation for [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) it shows:

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

So you can do:

```
$next.show().animate({marginTop: 0}, 2000, 'easeOutBounce', function () {
    $this.hide().css("z-index","0");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the speed of the animation and the type of easing in an options object and that should accomplish what you're looking for.

```
$next.show().animate({marginTop: 0}, {
     duration: 2000,
     easing: 'easeOutBounce'
    }, function () {
    $this.hide().css("z-index","0");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap into an object like this:

```
$next.show().animate(
    {marginTop: 0},
    {
        duration: 2000,
        specialEasing: {
            marginTop: "linear"
        },
        complete: function () {
            $this.hide().css("z-index","0");
        }
    }
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3xcu3urk/10/

Also, you need to load a plugin for the easeOutBounce http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

Comment: No you don't *need to*, there are several ways to add easing. It's an optional property in `.animation`, which you can use rather than adding it as a `options` object.

Comment: I see. I would rather use it, regardless, for better readability. And all the other answers here aren't stating that he has to load the easings plugin to be able to use 'easeOutBounce'.